# Vulnerablities for tomcat-embed-core in OWASP DependencyTrack

Tags: spring-boot, security, tomcat, owasp

We use OWASP DependencyTrack to keep track of vulnerablities in our Spring Boot apps.

SBOMs are generated using https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gradle-plugin and contain an entry for the embedded Tomcat server with a PURL such as

> pkg:maven/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core@10.0.26?type=jar

Checking the standard databases DependencyTrack does not find vulnerabilities published only for "normal" Tomcat (e.g. https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-42252).

Does anybody else face the same challenges? Do you have workarounds/solutions?

I am not sure where a solution for this might be applied (hint/additional information for enriching the generated SBOM?).

Comment: same here :/ . Did you find a solution/workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

A more broad question would be - why does OWASP checker flag a package as vulnerable, when the package is not listed as vulnerable in the corresponding vulnerability database.

This is a problem because the Maven dependency checker has to do a rather complicated task of determining which dependencies of the projects match which [CPEs](https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe) of published vulnerabilities.

The naming schemas of the two are completely incompatible with each other.

Maven dependency checker adopts a "when in doubt, sound an alarm" policy when making such comparison. If you look at the generated report, you will find that each match is annotated with a "confidence value", which indicates that the algorithm to match Maven packaging schema with CPE naming schema is fuzzy, and there isn't a way to safely make it deterministic.

The standard approach for these problems is tell the checker to have a CPE not apply to a package that you know is not vulnerable. The process is outlined in [its documentation](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/suppression.html).

In this particular case, you need to tell the dependency checker that "Tomcat embedded" (the actual dependency) is not Tomcat (what CPE is saying)

```xml
    <suppress base="true">
       <notes><![CDATA[
       Tomcat embed is not tomcat
       ]]></notes>
       <packageUrl regex="true">^pkg:maven/org\.apache\.tomcat\.embed/tomcat-embed.*@.*$</packageUrl>
       <cpe>cpe:/a:apache:tomcat</cpe>
    </suppress>
```

Comment: Hi Pawel, are you really really really sure that CVE-2022-42252 affects Tomcat but not Tomcat-embed ? Ain't that unexpected ? I'm no expert would would have expected that most CVE targetting Tomcat would also be valid problems in the embedded version...

Comment: Moreover, Snyk effectively tells that tomcat-embed is affected by CVE-2022-42252 : https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-ORGAPACHETOMCATEMBED-3097829

Comment: @FrancoisMarot The CPE listed in the NVD for this CVE suggest(!) that only tomcat itself is affected. If you have knowledge that tomcat-embed is also vulnerable, please contact ASF or NVD to have the CPE list extended.

Comment: More info here: https://github.com/DependencyTrack/dependency-track/discussions/3017#discussioncomment-7931037